# CreateView use parameters

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

In my Form I have a dropdown-list `projects`, which should show some elements based on a certain type, using `ModelChoiceField`. This query needs some parameter, but how do how can I pass this parameter to the form?

```
class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'project']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(TaskCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

\

```
class TaskcreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    projects = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.filter(type=someParameter))
    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `get_form()` method of the view.  For example if you provide this parameter via the `request.GET` then the view will be like this:

```
class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(TaskCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(
                                               type=self.request.GET['type'])
        return form
```

And in the form you can set the queryset to `none()`:

```
class TaskcreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    projects = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.none())
    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the get_form_kwargs method of the view:

```
class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'project']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(TaskCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
        """
        kwargs = super(TaskCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'my_var': 'my value'})
        return kwargs
```

And then capture that parameter in the form __init__ method.  You also need to set the queryset for the field in the __init__ method:

```
class TaskcreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    projects = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_var = kwargs.pop('my_var')
        super(TaskcreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['projects'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(type=self.my_var))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

You **must** use kwargs.pop() otherwise the call to `super()` will raise an error due to the unexpected keyword argument.

[CCBV](http://ccbv.co.uk) is a great resource for detailing the methods available on all of the generic class-based views.

Comment: you've made some typo's. should be   `kwargs.update({'my_var': 'my value'})`  ,  `__init__` , `type=self.my_var)`  . But now getting `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument `

Comment: That unexpected keyword is due to you not popping the parameter immediately in the form __init__, as I stated in the answer. Thanks for the heads-up about the typos, although a couple of them are due to trying to outwit the auto formatting

Answer (score 0):

Catavaran's answer is straight forward. Another option could be to add the type to the url pattern (untested syntax)

```
url(r'^create/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/$', TaskCreate.as_view(), name='create_task')
```

This way you'll receive the type via kwargs, and you'd still be able to create custom links to certain types using a reverse pattern

```
{% url 'create_task' type='foo' %}
```

Don't forget there's a chance you'll get bogus input from the GET param.